# Google Maps API reload marker location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map that is drawing markers for vehicles based on their GPS location inside a .json file. I'm running into problems getting the map to automatically reload the data from the .json file and then redraw the markers based on the new data/location. Here is some excerpts of my code:

```
const fetchAPI = async () => {
  const url = './cradlepoint.json';
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const locations = await response.json();
  return locations;
};

let data = await fetchAPI();
setInterval(fetchAPI,5000);
```

This is the fetch call that gets the location from the .json file and that's working fine; I confirmed that if the .json file changes, it brings in those changes. I added a setInterval to fire that every 5 seconds to grab new location data. Next I build the map and import that data:

```
async function initMap() {
    const { Map, InfoWindow, KmlLayer } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
    const { Marker } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
    map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      mapId: "####",
      center: { lat: ###, lng: ### },
      zoom: 14,
    });

  const busicon = "https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/bus.png";
  
  const infoWindow = new InfoWindow();

  function setMarker() {
  var results = data.data.length
  for (let i = 0; i < results; i++){
    var busid = data.data[i].id;
    var buslat = data.data[i].latitude;
    var buslong = data.data[i].longitude;
    const marker = new Marker({
      map: map,
      position: { lat: buslat, lng: buslong },
      icon: busicon,
      title: busid
    });
    // Add a click listener for each marker, and set up the info window.
    marker.addListener("click", ({ domEvent, latLng }) => {
    const { target } = domEvent;

    infoWindow.close();
    infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
    infoWindow.open(marker.map, marker);
    });
  };
  };

  setMarker()
  setInterval(setMarker,5000)

initMap();
```

I wrapped my create marker code into a function and then used setInterval to fire that every 5 seconds.

Both the fetch and the setmarker code is automatically running as expected, the problem is I can't get the updated location info coming out of the fetch call to dump into the "data" declaration.  I also suspect I need to add code to delete all markers and then re-draw them; but without getting the updated location data from the fetch, that's a moot point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are not updating the "data" variable with the new locations when calling to the fetchAPI ().
You are calling fetchAPI every 5 seconds but not assigning new values to "data".
Then you can change to :

```
let data;

const fetchAPI = async () => {
    //...
    //...
    //...
    //...
    const locations = await response.json();
    data = locations;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not `let data = await fetchAPI();` ? I suspect your problem is to construct all those functions into one process that occurs every 5 seconds? Maybe something like this pseudo-code:

```js
// globals
let map = null;
let previous_markers = null

// just for debug
function delay(millisec) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve()
    }, millisec);
  })
}

// fetching the json
async function fetch_data() {
  console.log("TODO: fetch data");
  await delay(1000);
  return new Array(3).fill(Math.round(Math.random()*10));

}

// setting markers
async function setMarkers(map, markers) {
  console.log("TODO: set markers on map: " + markers);
}

// removing markers
async function removeMarkers(map, markers) {
  console.log("TODO: remove markers from map: " + previous_markers);
}


// google map
function Map() {
  return "map";
}

// init map, draw map, remove markers, draw markers 
async function draw_map(markers) {
  if (map == null) {
    console.log("TODO: init map")
    map = new Map();
  }
  
  if (previous_markers) {
    removeMarkers(map, previous_markers);
  }
  
  setMarkers(map, markers)

  previous_markers = markers;
}

// the process function every 5 seconds
async function fetch_and_draw() {
  let markers = await fetch_data();
  draw_map(markers);
}

// main:
fetch_and_draw();
setInterval(fetch_and_draw, 5000);
```